# Is A diagonalizable? If yes find a matrix such that is a diagonal matrix, if not, find a matrix such that is Jordan

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, jordan-normal-form

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}
9&4&5
\\
-4&0&-3
\\
-6&-4&-2
\end{bmatrix}$ $\in$ $M_{3x3}$$(\mathbb{R})$.

Is A diagonalizable?

Justify your answer.

If yes, find a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is a diagonal matrix.

If not, find a matrix $Q$ such that $Q^{-1}AQ$ is the Jordan canonical form for A.  Write out the diagonal matrix or the Jordan canonical form.

Okay update, so I found out the matrix is not diagonalizable. However, I am having trouble understanding the theory behind representing the matrix in Jordan Form.

I have that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1,2}$ = 2 and $\lambda_{3}$ = 3.

Could someone please provide a nice explanation as to how I get  $Q^{-1}AQ$ as the Jordan canonical form for A.

Comment: Kindly include your attempt and describe where do you get stuck.

Comment: where should i begin?

Comment: what do you know about diagonalization?

Comment: in this case the matrix is not diagonalizable since its eigenvectors are not linearly independent

Comment: $A$ is not diagonalizable, because it fails the diagonalizability test.or use the fact "an nxn matrix is diagonalizable iff it has n linearly independent eigenvectors"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test for Diagonalization:

Let $T$ be a linear operator on an n-dimensional vector space $V$. Then $T$
is diagonalizable if and only if both of the following conditions hold.

1. The characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits.
2. For each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $T$, the multiplicity of $\lambda$ equals $n - rank(T — \lambda I).$

Here, $2,2,3$ are the eigenvalues.

But multiplicity of $2$ = $2 \neq 3-rank(A-2I)$, since $rank(A-2I)=2$

Comment: ok perfect! so now how do i find the matrix Q such that Q-1QA is the jordan canonical form for A

Comment: There are totally two linearly independent eigenvectors, hence there are two blocks in JCF, namely a 2x2 block corresponding to 2 and one single 1x1 block corresponding to 3.

Comment: can you please give symbolics? or a link to a good example

Comment: could you please expand on the jordan canonical form

Answer (score 0):

**A** is diagonalizable iff **A** is nondefective, i.e., the dimension of **A**'s eigenspace is the same with its generalized eigenspace.
Or you can directly calculate its Jordan canonical form. For the diagonalizable matrix, it automatically turns to be a diagonal matrix.

Comment: in this case the matrix is not diagonalizable since its eigenvectors are not linearly independent

Answer (score 0):

I should check and find its eigenvalues. if you found its eigenvalues and they are not independent so A is not diagonalizable. because the columns of Q(3 by 3 matrix) are linear independent eigenvectors of A. This is a theorem.